# Decay estimates for transport equations in massless case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, kinematics, transport-equation

Considering the kinetic-transport equation $f(t,x,p)$ in the mass shell. It is well known that in the classic case (Vlasov non-relativistic)

\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v)dv &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f^0(x-vt,v)dv \\
     &\leq  \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\ f^0(x-vt,w)dv,
\end{align*}
for $t>0$, we can apply the change of variable $y=x-vt$ and the appropriate scaling to get the decay estimates
\begin{align*}
    \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v)dv \right| &\leq \frac{1}{t^3}\sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}^3 } \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left|f^0(y,w)\right|dy \\
    &\leq \frac{C}{t^3}.
\end{align*}

Otherwise, for the massive case (relativistic with $m>0$) applying the change of variable $y=x-\frac{v}{v^0}t$ we can obtain

\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} | f(t,x,v)|dv    &\leq   \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\ f^0(x-\frac{v}{v^0}t,v)dv. \\
& \leq  \frac{C}{t^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\ \sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}^3}|f^0(y,w)|dy,
\end{align*}
where $C$ depends support in $v$.

For more details, see https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/smulevici/lgke.pdf.

My question is:

For massless case where $v^0 = |v|$ (with $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $|v|=\sqrt(v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^3)$ ) with the compact support assumption in $v$, the decay estimate falls off like $t^{-2}$, but the above changes of variables still gives me t^{-3}.
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v)dv &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f^0(x-\frac{v}{|v|}t,v)dv \\
     &\leq  \ \ \ ?
\end{align*}

Any help or suggestions on what to do?
The idea is to continue using the characteristics method.

---

**EDIT:**

The idea seems to be to pass the integral of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to an appropriate sphere (of radius $r$ and centered at $0$), i.e. using polar coordinates in the variable $v$.

1. Using $v= (v_1,v_2,v_3) = (r \sin \phi \cos \theta, r \sin \phi \sin \theta, r \cos \phi) = \omega$ , we have that $|v| = |r| = r$.

Thus,
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}  f(t,x,v)dv    &=   \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\ f^0(x-\frac{v}{|v|}t,v)dv \\
& =  \int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\ f^0(x-\frac{\omega}{r}t,\omega) r^2 \sin \phi d\omega
\end{align*}

????   However, I can't see how to get the t^-2.

2. To write $\omega=\frac{v}{|v|}$, $r=|v|$ so that $dv=r^2 dr d\omega$ where $r\in(0,\infty)$ and $\omega \in S^2$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
    \int_{v \in \mathbb{R}^3}  f(t,x,v)dv    &=   \int_{v \in \mathbb{R}^3}\ f^0(x-\frac{v}{|v|}t,v)dv \\
& =  \int_{\omega \in \mathbb{S}^2}\ f^0(x-\omega t,r\omega) r^2 dr d\omega
\end{align*}

Now, should I change the variables again?

---

Some questions about it:

1. Should take the sphere of radius $t$?, or
2. Does this change of variables make sense?

\begin{align*}
     \int_{\omega \in \mathbb{S}^2}\ f^0(x-\omega t,r\omega) r^2 dr d\omega & \leq C_r \sup_{r \geq 0} \int_{\omega \in \mathbb{S}^2}\  f^0(x-\omega t,\omega) d\omega \\
& \leq \frac{C_r}{t^{-2}} \sup_{r \geq 0} \int_{y \in \mathbb{S}^2}\  f^0(x-y, \frac{ry}{t}) dy
\end{align*}

Comment: The issue with trying to get $t^{-3}$ decay with the usual change of variables in the massless case is that the map $v\mapsto x-\frac{v}{|v|}t$ is not injective (velocities with the same direction but different magnitudes will be mapped to the same characteristic line). The $t^{-2}$ decay comes from making an analogous change of variables but on an appropriate sphere, which can be accomplished by writing the integral of $f$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: I see...in that case, if I integrate with respect to $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is it enough to change coordinates $v_1=R\sin\theta \cos\phi,  v_2=R\sin\theta \sin\phi,  v_3=R\cos\theta$, with R the radius of the ball containing the support? 
Or should I do the same with $x \in  \mathbb{R}^3$?
The fact that $f$ is 7 variables in the mass-shell confuses me. 

Thanks for your comments @kieransquared !

Comment: This should probably work, although the exact choice of coordinates on the sphere shouldn’t matter much. It would equally suffice to write $\omega = v/|v|$, $s=|v|$ so that $dv = s^2 dsd\omega$ where $s\in (0,\infty)$ and $\omega\in S^2$.

Comment: Thanks again, I have edited the entry adding the suggestions you have given me. However, it is not clear to me how to obtain the expected decay after trying some changes of variables. If you could give me a little more detail on the expected change I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but one way is as follows. Using polar coordinates $r=|v|$, $v = r\omega$ we may write

$$\int f(t,x,v) dv = \int_0^\infty \int_{S^2} f^0(x-t\omega,r\omega) d\omega dr$$

Then, *on the sphere* (rather than the whole space) we make the change of variables $\omega\mapsto t\omega = \gamma$, and you can compute the Jacobian explicitly as $|J| = t^2$ (you can verify this by direct calculation using the usual coordinates on the sphere, but you don't even need an explicit choice of coordinates, because this map is a scaling of the identity). Then, $d\gamma = |J| d\omega$, so that

$$\int f(t,x,v) dv = t^{-2}\int_0^\infty \int_{S^2} f^0(x-\gamma,rt^{-1}\gamma) d\gamma dr \leq t^{-2}\sup_{x,v}\int_0^\infty\int_{S^2} f^0(x-\gamma,v)d\gamma dr$$